# JavaFx Scene builder : CSS is not loading in ubuntu but working on Windows

Tags: css, ubuntu, javafx, javafx-2, scenebuilder

I am working on adding CSS file in an Fxml file like below.

```
<BorderPane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="1200.0" stylesheets="@../../../resources/css/home.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.ctc.controller.SupplierUpdateController">
```

As you can see I have added the css like `stylesheets="@../../../resources/css/home.css"`

This has done by using scene builder in windows and it worked fine.
But when I have created the jar and run on ubuntu 16.04, the CSS does not get applied and there is following error in the console.

```
Oct 15, 2017 6:18:02 PM com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager loadStylesheetUnPrivileged
INFO: Could not load stylesheet: rsrc:../../../resources/css/home.css
```

This was working properly when I am running the application while in eclipse in ubuntu. But for the ar created it is not taking the CSS files.

Comment: I am sure that the jar is not going to work on windows too. You need to specify the full path and replace all the '../..' with the correct folders name

Comment: This is working in windows without any issue. And when I create the jar with Intellij IDEA it worked perfectly in ubuntu too

Comment: Mr Lister, actually this is not a web application. It is a JavaFx Desktop application.

Comment: @ChamaleeDeSilva Sorry about that. But my point still stands: if you have a subdirectory named Resources, Windows won't mind if you refer to it by "resources" in the application. Ubuntu does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once had similar issues when I didn't place the FXML-file itself within the resources-folder. The resources-entry within your path suggests that your FXML-file also seems to be outside the resouces-folder. Try the following structure:

```
resources/css/home.css
resources/your/package/yourlayout.fxml
```

Then referencing `"@../../css/home.css"` inside the yourlayout.fxml should be no problem anymore.